# Correct way to create and remove/destroy DOM element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, dom, createelement

#### Explanation:

I have an ASP.NET application, where I can retrieve Vehicle information with a click of a button. The Vehicle detail is then displayed in a modal screen with the following data: ID, VEHICLENAME,YEAR, and VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION.

The VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION is displayed in anchor tags, which is created using JavaScript. The expectation is when I retrieve Vehicle detail, their relevant VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION would be displayed, and created in an anchor tag. If another Vehicle detail is retrieved, their relevant VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION would also be created in an anchor tag.

The problem I'm encountering is when anchor tag are created for a Vehicle detail, I can not create anchor tags for the next time I retrieve another Vehicle detail. I have outlined the errors I keep getting below.

I've provided the full working code below, including the error message I encounter. Hopefully someone could assist me.

#### DetailController:

```
DetailController:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDetail(int? id)
{
  return _context.Vehicle.Where(v => v.ID == id).Select(x => new VehicleModel(){
     ID = x.ID,
     VEHICLENAME = x.VEHICLENAME,
     YEAR = x.YEAR,
     VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION = x.VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION
  }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

#### Detail Razor Page:

```
Button
------
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailModal" onclick="postData(id)"></button>

Modal window appears when button is clicked
-------------------------------------------
<div class="modal fade" id="detailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="detailModalTitle">Vehicle Detail</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ID: <label id="ID"></label><br />
                VEHICLE NAME: <label id="VEHICLENAME"></label><br />
                YEAR: <label id="YEAR"></label><br />
                VEHICLE DOCUMENTATION: <label id="VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION"></label><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

AJAX POST to GetDetail method:
------------------------------
<script>
function postData(id) {
   response = '';
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Detail/GetDetail",
                data: { 'id': id},
                success: function (xhr) {
                    response = xhr;
                    $('#ID').text(response.data.ID);
                    $('#VEHICLENAME').text(response.data.VEHICLENAME);
                    $('#YEAR').text(response.data.YEAR);
                    $('#VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION').text(response.data.VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION);

                    //Create anchor tags
                    if (response.data.VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION.length !== 0) {
                        for (const doc of response.data.VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION) {
                            const anchor = document.createElement('a');
                            const list = document.getElementById('VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION');
                            const li = document.createElement('ol');
                            anchor.href = 'www.vehicledocumentationexample.com';
                            anchor.innerText = `${doc}`;
                            
                            //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS BEING FLAGGED:
                            li.appendChild(anchor);
                            list.appendChild(li);
                        }
                   //Delete/Remove elements
                    } else if (response.data.VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION.length == 0) {
                        response.data.VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION = [];
                        document.getElementById("VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION").outerHTML = "";
            
                       //WHAT I'VE TRIED:
                       //document.getElementById('VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION').remove();
                       //document.getElementById('VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION').outerHTML = "";
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    response = xhr;
                }
            })

}
</script>
```

#### Browser error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at Object.success (...)
    at fire (jquery.js:3240)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3370)
    at done (jquery.js:9061)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9303)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you put:

```
 document.getElementById("VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION").outerHTML = "";
```

What you are doing is to erase the label element, so when you call it from

```
const list = document.getElementById('VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION');
```

It will return null as the element do not exist anymore

Instead of using "outerHTML" you should use "innerHTML", here it is the difference between them:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION").outerHTML);

console.log(document.getElementById("VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION").innerHTML);
```

```html
<label id="VEHICLE_DOCUMENTATION">
  <p>something</p>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. You've helped me so much!!